# Drag & Drop - Check item was dropped in the correct place

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm teaching myself javascript/jquery and decided as a side project to create a drag and drop game. I've based it on other tutorials I've found and just adapted it really, so go easy on the code - hopefully its not too scary.

I'm using the jquery ui dropable library to implement the game and currently I check once the item is dropped if it is in the correct place, if it is I increment the score by one.

However the problem I have is I can't get the score to go down by one when the item is dropped in the wrong place.

If a square is placed on the correct placeholder it adds 1 to the score but if that same square gets removed from the correct place holder then it needs to take 1 off the score.

Heres a demo here of what I've done so far
http://creativelabel.co.uk/drag-and-drop/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to store in the dropped element whether it was placed in a valid square. This means when it is moved to an invalid square you can check if it was previously in a valid one and if this is the case reduce the score by one.

Hope this is clear!

See http://jsfiddle.net/pET3y/ for a live demo

Relevant code:

```
  if ( slotNumber == imgNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'img-match' );
    ui.draggable.data("valid", true);

    imgMatch++;
  }  else {
      if(ui.draggable.data("valid")) {
         imgMatch--;
         ui.draggable.data("valid", false); 
      }
  }
```

*Note: the the fiddle has an alert `alert(ui.draggable.data("valid"));` for debug*

--

**Changing for on drag the score goes down**

What you do now is listen for the *drag* event (called `activate`), and when this is called run a function. The function checks if the element being dragged was previously in the correct position and if it was, marks it as not in the correct position and decreases the score.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/3NkwJ/1/

```
      drop: handleDropEvent,
      activate: handleDragEvent //add new event
} );
```

And add the below:

```
  function handleDragEvent( event, ui ) {
    if(ui.draggable.data("valid")) {
             imgMatch--;
             $('input[name=Score]').val(imgMatch);
             $('#score h1').text(imgMatch);
             ui.draggable.data("valid", false); 
    }      
  }
```

Comment: That works if I drag the item on to another square, is there a way to make it remove the score straight away on drag?

So if drop is correct add to score but as soon as its picked up again it removes score.

Comment: Nice one, worked a treat. I hadn't come across activate event until now. I was looking into the out event for a solution but no luck. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now to add the timer, that shouldn't be too hard. Thanks again.

Comment: Good luck, would be interested to see it when it's finished

Comment: I'm using this as a reference and in turn hopefully helping someone else with a similar problem. Currently the game allows you to drag more than one square on top of another. I'm working on disabling the drop when a square has already been dropped. I'll post my answer when I get somewhere. If anyone has any ideas in the mean time...?

Answer (score 0):

i only skimmed the code but after this block

```
if ( slotNumber == imgNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'img-match' );
    imgMatch++;
}
```

can you just add an else statement

```
else
    imgMatch--;
```

Comment: An else statement won't work, if you drop it in an invalid place 5 times the score is -5, but it should be 0.

Comment: ah i see, your answer covers everything much better anyway